# 16x16 table filled with hex values in tikz with foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a beginner to Latex and Tikz. I'm facing the following problem: I want to create a table with hex values from `00` to `FF` in tikz using for each. However, is there a way to specify hex values with other variables? Currently, the example in TikZ manual uses the existing variables in the loop like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
\foreach \y in {0,1,2,3}
{
\draw (\x,\y) circle (0.2cm);
\fill (\x,\y) circle (0.1cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It uses the `x` and `y` variables, but how do I specify my own variable, with hex values for each node?

Comment: You should look up how to use counters, and then perhaps use the `moreenum` package to convert counter values to hex.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest keeping yourself and TeX in decimal, and converting to hex as needed for presentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fmtcount} % for hex conversion
\newcounter{somevalue}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \row in {0, ..., 15}
{
  \foreach \col in {0, ..., 15}
  {
    \node[xshift=\col cm, yshift=-\row em]
      {0x\padzeroes[2]\Hexadecimalnum{\thesomevalue}};
    \stepcounter{somevalue}
  };
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: pgfmath knows about hex numbers `hex(x)` and `Hex(x)` can do the conversion on integers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I add `draw` to the `\node`, the table is not rendered properly. Could we use `grid` for a proper table? I cannot make the borders overlap correctly with xshift and yshift.

Comment: Not knowing what you want to draw, I can't say. The usual tabular designs tend to not add grids or excess lines.

Comment: Well, what if I want to draw something similar to the periodic table? Those tables tend to have grid, but width big square boxes .

Comment: At 16x16 on a normal portrait sheet of paper and typical font sizes, those boxes won't be large, but I'll see what I can come up with if someone doesn't beat me to it.